# Where did my Nvidia optimus card go?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have an Asus UX32VD that has a Nvidia 620M card along with the integrated Intel graphics. I had Ubuntu 13.04 and I could use the Nvidia card with bumblebee for some time, then I it stopped working after a kernel or drivers update(don't remember) and I was busy and lazy to fix it and I didn't really missed using the card.

Then I found there is a partial support from Nvidia for the Optimus technology but it required newer packages versions, I also checked the `nvidia-prime` package in saucy-salamander made the setup completely painless so I said, What the.. lets upgrade to 13.10 to test the new feature.

I purged bumblebee and everything related to Nvidia and once I had my saucy install working I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers followed by the nvidia-prime package. Now I restart and ... surprise!(actually not a surprise,something like this always happens) no UI, a low graphics mode message and there I am.

Of course I didn't check before the installation with `lspci` if I had an optimus capable PC because I HAVE AN OPTIMUS CAPABLE PC but doing `lspci` or checking in `dmeseg` output I don't see any trace of the nvidia word, my card just disapeared.

Now I don't know how to fix it or what could be the cause. I can only think of two options, a fairy opened my pc and stole the Nvidia chipset while I was sleeping or in the bumblebee time my card got disabled(bbswitch?) and now the system doesn't detect it.

Comment: Well, Saucy is still in active development and is not even in beta, so really that is not a surprise at all. While running a development version you must expect that something may not work, or even that an update breaks something that works...

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get nvidia optimus working right out of the box, you can either install Suacy 13.10 which will give you nvidia optimus or you have install latest 12.04.3 which is LTS and has patched kernel, xrand R and will run fine as well. I have ASUS i7 laptop with Nvidia running very well with nvidia prime and nvidia optimus. The reason it didn't work in 13.04 is due to older xorg and xrandR.